# Extract ER Diagram from an existing DB (SQL Server)

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I have a pretty messy DB with a weird tangle of keys.
Can you suggest me a software (better if it's free) that can extract the ER schema from the DB?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ER-Studio, CA-ErWin and even Toad has some reverse engineering capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SchemaCrawler for SQL Server](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/bundled.html), and take a look at it's [diagramming capabilities](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/diagramming.html). It is free and open source. I would recommend that you don't export the whole database diagram at once. Instead, try to explore one set of relationships at a time. For example, if you want to explore customer relationships, without confusing yourself with say order information, you can use SchemaCrawler's grep to generate a partial diagram. [image: SchemaCrawler diagram].

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/)